# Yii create PDF Thumbnail with ImageMagick

Tags: php, yii, imagemagick

I want to create auto Thumbnail if i upload my PDF, then i will save that path
i build my website with **yii** framework
i want to try capture with **ImageMagick**
Any Body Help..
Thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, change title and retag your question. It has in fact nothing to do with Yii itself and could be little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Yii framework to generate the image file. It is pretty simple and straight forward. I am using window XP/apache and php 5.4

1. Download and install the imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php
2. Download and install php extension for imagemagic http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
3. Download and install the ghostscript because image magic use the ghost script to convert the pdf to images http://www.ghostscript.com/download/
4. Write a method in your model class to handle conversion

   use command : [command format](http://snipplr.com/view/48513)         OR

   use library : [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)
5. Call the method after your form submission.

check if the image is saved at the desired location. I hope that help. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Why use convert command instead of library?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: just the personal preference

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that on some shared hostings using exec() will not be possible. No offence. Just little addendum.
Besides I think using library is little bit cleaner.

Comment: @shark555 thanks for the suggestion and I have modified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I know you asked about ImageMagick but maybe you could use GD instead to accomplish such simple operation.
It's available virtually on every hosting.

Examples in comments below docs.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: GD does not support the reading of PDFs.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php